# Angular2 material 'md-icon' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have angular2 application which is using @angular2-material 2.0.0-alpha.8-2 version. Everything works fine. 
Now I decided to upgrade material version to latest i.e. 2.0.0-alpha.9-3. I followed steps mentioned in [GETTING_STARTED](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).
Earlier I had imported individual modules as below:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,

    MdIconModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,

    ....
    ....
```

However change log of 2.0.0-alpha.9-3 version says:

"Angular Material has changed from  @angular2-material/...  packages to a single package under @angular/material . Along with this change, there is a new NgModule,  MaterialModule , that contains all of the components."

So I removed explicitly imported material modules and changed it to:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,

    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ....
    ....
```

After this change I am getting following error

'md-icon' is not a known element:

1. If 'md-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-icon' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Do I need to import individual modules explicitly or as mentioned in change log MaterialModule contains all components and I should not explicitly import individual modules? If I shouldn't import individual modules then what could be source of error?

Comment: For me this happens only with Karma/Jasmine tests with 'Template parse errors: 'md-icon' is not a known element"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What about the `export` section? Did you provide `MaterialModule` there?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule
  ]
})
```

Remember to provide icon styles in your index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

After that you should be able to use icons in your views:

```
<md-icon>delete</md-icon>
```

Comment: Yes. I have material icons styles included. However do we need to export material modules? I believe that's already exported by MaterialModule. If I again export it then won't it get exported twice and show ambiguity error as it will be exported twice?

Comment: If you have more then one module in your app. For example you are using "sharedModule" you need to reexport moduels which you want to use in modules which are importing that "sharedModule". I am not sure, how it works, when you got one-module-app. I bielieve that you have more then one module, that's why you run into issue with `material`.

Comment: Well, this doesn't work now with NG 4.3.5 and NG-material 2.0.0-beta8

Answer (score 17):

You need to import **MatIconModule** in app.module.ts and add it to your imports array in the same file.

Like this for example:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { TreeModule } from "angular-tree-component";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon"; // <----- Here

import { EclassService } from "./services/eclass.service";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AsyncTreeComponent } from "./components/async-tree/async-tree.component";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AsyncTreeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, TreeModule, HttpClientModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule // <--- HERE
  ],
  providers: [EclassService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for newer material versions

Comment: I already did. Imported individual material components and exported too in app.module.ts. But neither work out. The error seems same for material modules and even ngForm as well. However, it's also imported fine.

Comment: If it still doesn't work check for unrelated syntax errors in your NgModule such trying to  import a non-existing/deleted module.

Answer (score 11):

if you load a child module like this:

```
{path: 'childModule', loadChildren: 'app/child/child.module#childModule'}
```

then in child module, you have to import MaterialModule again.
e.g.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        sharedModules,
        childRouting,
        MaterialModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class childModule {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

to `index.html`

and `<i class="material-icons">delete</i>` instead of `<md-icon>delete</md-icon>`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is adding md-icon, md-input, etc modules and style sheet.

You would also need to add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA as below in app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

then add

```js
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

Answer (score 2):

Two steps to use mat-icon:

1. insert this into index.html file.

   ```
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
      rel="stylesheet">
   ```
2. insert this line into app.module.ts file. If performing lazy loading then include it 
       in that module or in sharedModule.

   ```
   import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add this 
to index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

and add to app.module.ts file this:

```
import {
  MatIconModule
} from '@angular/material';

imports: [MatIconModule]
```