# Angular2 material 'md-chips' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on an Angular2 application using @angular/material 2.0.0-beta.2 and I am trying to use [Chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips), but I get `'md-chips' is not a known element`. Here is what I have done:

component.html:

```
<md-chips ng-model="keywords" readonly="false" placeholder="Enter a keyword"></md-chips>
```

module.ts

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';
...
@NgModule({
imports: [
    productRouting,
    SharedModule,
    Select2Module,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
],
...
```

if I use some other material component like

```
<md-toolbar color="primary"><span>GameViewer</span></md-toolbar>
```

I'll have no problem, therefor I don't think I have a problem with importing the material module.

P.S. I already read these:

- [Angular2 material 'md-icon' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40291930/1991808)
- [Angular2 material 'md-icon' is not a known element with Karma / Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198981/1991808)
- [Material design component “is not a known element” in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40195550/1991808)

Comment: asfaik, there's the `mat` prefixes are should to be used instead of `md` ones in the material `beta.2`

Comment: @WildDev It's still `md`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Material2 the components are **md-chip** and **md-chip-list**.

```
<md-chip-list>
  <md-chip>Papadum</md-chip>
  <md-chip>Naan</md-chip>
  <md-chip>Dal</md-chip>
</md-chip-list>
```

The docs can be found [here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/chips).

Comment: Thanks. So [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.2/demo/chips) is for AngularJS? I just noticed the "js" in the link!

Comment: @Kavoos yep they have only recently put up the new site. There is quite a bit on GitHub too https://github.com/angular/material2.